# <base target="_blank"> in head does not open links in new tab or window

Tags: html, target, radix, head

On this [page on my website](https://www.diningbonaire.fyi/bamboo-bali-bonaire/) I need all links to open in a new tab/window. I added `<base target="_blank">`in the `<head>` and that worked for a couple of days. Today all of a sudden it does not work any longer.. I also tried to add this script `<script>$("body.page-template-plain a").attr("target","_blank");</script>` but that doesn't work either. I hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an error showing in the console. `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`. Seems to be thrown from the script tag in the question.

Comment: The links in this website seems to have a click event handler which is opening the `href` url using `window.open`. Check your code.

Comment: Hi NiK648, I got rid of the script. It was just a second try.. I don't understand why <base target="_blank"> doesn't work. I don't think the 'MORE INFO >' buttons have click event handlers so that can't be the reason right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The issue is due to vc_gitem-link class which does not support opening the link in a new tab. You can target it html custom js to remove the class added to it." This was the answer of the Visual Composer plugin developers.

Answer (score 0):

This script should work

```
let myLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for (let link of myLinks) {
  link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/YaPNvR/

Answer (score 0):

target="_self" might be the problem in the links:

```
<a target="_self" href="http://link.to">
```